# Excel cycle through validation list and export as Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have

-worksheet name "sheet2:

-Datavalidation list in G1

looking if there's a way to have macro that cycles through the data validation list and exports a workbook with the name of the text in that cell and loop through so every item of list exports as their own workbook  . aka if there's 100 lines in the drop down, then i'd end with 100 excel files each individually named for the 100 drop down options.

Example , This worked for me to print out pdfs :

```
Public Sub Create_PDFs()

Dim destinationFolder As String
Dim dataValidationCell As Range, dataValidationListSource As Range, dvValueCell As Range

destinationFolder = "C:\Users\DELL 04\Desktop\Q-Book Activities\Experiment"     'Same folder as workbook containing this macro
'destinationFolder = "C:\path\to\folder\"  'Or specific folder

If Right(destinationFolder, 1) <> "\" Then destinationFolder = destinationFolder & "\"
     
'Cell containing data validation in-cell dropdown

Set dataValidationCell = Worksheets("sheet2").Range("G1")
 
'Source of data validation list

Set dataValidationListSource = Evaluate(dataValidationCell.Validation.Formula1)
 
'Create PDF for each data validation value

For Each dvValueCell In dataValidationListSource
    dataValidationCell.Value = dvValueCell.Value
    With dataValidationCell.Worksheet.Range("A1:I45")
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=destinationFolder & dvValueCell.Value & ".PDF", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End With
Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: Try replacing `.ExportAsFixedFormat` with `ActiveWorkbook.saveas` and use the necessary specific parameters. Of course, change the extension for `FileName` and use the appropriate `FileFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you just use the same, working code, and create workbooks instead?

```
For Each dvValueCell In dataValidationListSource
    Workbooks.Add.SaveAs Filename:=destinationFolder & dvValueCell
    Workbooks(dvValueCell & ".xlsx").Close
Next
```

Comment: This just saves all the workbooks as blank , no data

Comment: Yes? I can't see that you said that you wanted anything else? Except that you say "export", but never what is supposed to be in the file. Unless I'm just missing someting. I guess you wanted to do the same thing as you did with the PDFs, which in hindsight makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing of:

```
.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=destinationFolder & dvValueCell.Value & ".PDF", _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

with

```
Worksheets("sheet2").Copy 'it creates a new workbook with Sheet2 content
ActiveWorkbook.saveAs Filename:=destinationFolder & dvValueCell.Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault 
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

Comment: This did the job , But it is saving Sheet 1 as well . Is there any way to get rid of sheet one . Without the data entered in sheet2 to change due to missing links .. And save only sheet2

Comment: @maqlly I will adapt the code to save only Sheet2 as many times as many lines exist in the drop down. Adapted. Please, test it and send some feedback.

Comment: Your are a true legend not gonna lie , Worked Perfectly .. Just tweaked it to copy only the values rather than formulas , Thank you

Comment: @maqlly You did not say anything about formulas transformation... I do not know how you did it, but best way should be creating a range `rng`) of cells having formulas (at once, using SpecialCells) and simple use `rng.value = rng.value`. Anyhow, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for something similar will know that the code works...